# How to create Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I am developing a desktop application... I am trying to create a crystal report in Visual studio 2010... I searched for a whole day but I didn't find any solution for my problem... I have installed the add-ins for VS10 and now I want to create one report of my data from a dataset. I am using access as my database... I also want to ask that if I create the setup of this project and run that in a system where Crystal reports is not installed will it work? Please give me some steps to create report... Help me please...

Thank you in advance....

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual  Also see this one as well.http://softmate-technologies.com/CrystalReports13.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have installed Crystal Reports for Visual Studio which can be found here. http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
2. I usually create views to fetch the data that I want to be displayed. You can add the views to your dataset.
3. You can make a new Crystal Reports by going to Add New Item -> Reports -> Crystal Reports.
4. In Visual Studio, while your new report is still in view, you should see the the Crystal Reports Menu, click on it and then click on Field Explorer.
5. You can then right click on Database Field to setup and set the datasource location of your report. The fields will then be in view to drag and drop.
6. You will need to create a report viewer to see the report and code appropriately for it.

There are many articles on how to create CR reports in Visua Studio like these two.
http://www.codemag.com/Article/0207021
This one may be based on a ASP.NET project but the procedure for creating one is basically the same. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual

This is a good one to follow step by step.